# Can't infer embedded type arguments from type

Tags: c#, generics

I came from the c++ corner and have some unterstanding issues with c# generics.

**Questions:**

- Why does the following code not working?
- Do you have some links for me to improve my generic knowledge?

**Definitions**

```
public abstract class Item{}
public abstract class ParentItem<T> : Item where T : Item{
    public ObservableCollection<T> Childs;
}
public class ItemC : Item {}
public class ItemB : ParentItem<ItemC> {}
public class ItemA : ParentItem<ItemB> {}


public void NewChildItem<P, C>(P parent) where P : ParentItem<C> where C : Item, new()
{
    C child = new C();
    parent.Childs.Add(child); //From class ParentItem
}

public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public object Parent;
}
```

**Usage**

```
public void NewItem(MyEventArgs e)
{
    datas.NewChildItem(e.Parent);          // That would be nice to avoid case analysis
    datas.NewChildItem(e.Parent as ItemA); // Error cant resolve paramter type

//Following variant works, but is obvious ugly
    if(e.Parent is ParentItem<ItemA>)
        datas.NewChildItem<ParentItem<ItemA>,ItemA>(e.Parent as ParentItem<ItemA>)
    else if(e.Parent is ParentItem<ItemB>)
        datas.NewChildItem<ParentItem<ItemB>,ItemB>(e.Parent as ParentItem<ItemB>)
}
```

**Explanation**

I have a TreeView with HierarchicalDataTemplate over 3 Layers. 
My datastructure:

```
ItemA
    -ItemB
    -ItemB
        -ItemC
ItemA
    -ItemB
        -ItemC
```

With the contextmenu i want to add a child. I fire MyEvent to get the parent(null if root) which should create a new child.

If i have design errors, please tell me. I want to get better.

Comment: What is your definition of `ParentItem<T>`? And `e.Parent as ParentItem<ItemA>` is not the same as `e.Parent as ItemA`

Comment: @m.rogalski I added the definitions

Comment: This is not compiling: ItemA is can not inherit ParantItem<ItemB> because ParentItem<ItemB> is not inherited from Item!

Comment: From what I know the constraints must be the same in both so `public abstract class ParentItem<T> where T : Item{` should match `NewChildItem<P, C>(P parent) where P : ParentItem<C> where C : Item, new()` so you have to either add `, new()` at the class definition or remove `new()` on method implementation. Another thing is that in method you've checked `e.Parent as ItemA` instead of `e.Parent as ParentItem<ItemA>` which may cause some issues.

Comment: @kara you are right. I fergot the inheritance. I added it to the definition.

Comment: Here is a working example: https://ideone.com/tlvvQ8.

Answer (score 0):

I think you did it the wrong way. You want to have Items with children. And you can generate children for your generic item:

```
    // Master-class with business-logic or so..
    public abstract class Item
    {
        private static int nextId = 0; // Some Id-generator
        public Item()
        {
            this.Id = nextId++;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; } // Id to see the difference between the objects.

        public string Name { get { return this.GetType().Name + ":" + this.Id; } } // For Console..
    }

    // Class with business-logic for items which can have children
    public abstract class ItemWithChildren<TChildClass> : Item where TChildClass : Item, new()
    {
        public ItemWithChildren()
        {
            this.Childs = new ObservableCollection<TChildClass>();
        }
        public ObservableCollection<TChildClass> Childs { get; set; }

        public Item NewChildItem()
        {
            TChildClass newItem = new TChildClass();
            Childs.Add(newItem);
            return newItem;
        }

        public List<Item> GetChildItemsTypeless()
        {
            return this.Childs.Select(s => (Item) s).ToList();
        }
    }

    // implementation of you concrete types..
    public class ItemA : ItemWithChildren<ItemB>, IItemWithChildren { }
    public class ItemB : ItemWithChildren<ItemC>, IItemWithChildren { }
    public class ItemC : Item { }

    // interface for managing children
    public interface IItemWithChildren
    {
        Item NewChildItem();
        List<Item> GetChildItemsTypeless();
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        // Lets build some Items with an hierarchy
        ItemA a = new ItemA();
        ItemB b = (ItemB)a.NewChildItem(); // We cast here to explicit type to show that it's working.
        Item b2 = a.NewChildItem(); // Here we got our anonymous Item
        ItemC c = (ItemC)b.NewChildItem();
        Item c2 = b.NewChildItem();

        // Lets build an anonymous list - like your args-object
        List<Item> items = new List<Item>() {a, b, b2, c, c2};

        // some target for our new children..
        List<Item> allItems = new List<Item>();

        // let's add some children
        foreach (Item item in items)
        {
            allItems.Add(item);
            IItemWithChildren itemWithchildren = item as IItemWithChildren;

            if (itemWithchildren != null)
                allItems.Add(itemWithchildren.NewChildItem());
        }

        Console.WriteLine(" - - - Items with their children - - -");
        foreach (Item item in allItems)
        {
            IItemWithChildren itemWithchildren = item as IItemWithChildren;
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name + (itemWithchildren != null ? ": " + String.Join(", ", itemWithchildren.GetChildItemsTypeless().Select(s => s.Name)) : ""));
        }
        Console.WriteLine(" - - - Items by hierarchy - - -");
        PrintItem(a);
    }

    public static void PrintItem(Item i, int level = 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" ".PadRight(level*4) + i.Name);
        IItemWithChildren itemWithchildren = i as IItemWithChildren;
        if (itemWithchildren != null)
        {
            foreach (Item x in itemWithchildren.GetChildItemsTypeless())
            {
                PrintItem(x, level + 1);
            }
        }
    }
```

`Item` is your "master-class" with some business-logic.

`ItemWithChildren<T>` class with the business-logic which can generate new children.
`IItemWithChildren` is the managing interface which knows that you got children.

By moving the `NewchildItem` to the abstract `ItemWithChildren` you don't even need to know the class anywhere.
The interface `IItemWithChildren` is needed to add children without knowing the exact generic parameter T from `ItemWithChildren<T>`

Comment: One point is missing. I got an object from MyEventArgs. If the object is null, i have to add a new ItemA to my collection. But what if parent is ItemA or ItemB?

Comment: Okay: You're facing the problem, that you got two types of classes - with and without children. But you don't want to name the class ItemWithChildren<T> because of the generic T, which you don't want to know (`if` `as` .. too much code). Easiest way would be an interface for those classes with chldren. I'll add it to the code..